Is every continuous function $g$ of the form $g(p) = \|f\|_p$ for some $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$?
Let $1 \leq a \leq b \leq \infty$, and let $f \in L_a(\mathbb R) \cap L_b(\mathbb R)$. Then the function $g : [a,b] \to [0,\infty)$, $p \mapsto \|f\|_p$, is continuous. We also have that if there is $p \in [a,b]$ such that $g(p) = 0$, then $g$ is identically zero.
Conversely, let $1 \leq a \leq b \leq \infty$, and let $g : [a,b] \to (0,\infty)$ be a continuous function.
Question: Does there exist $f \in L_a(\mathbb R) \cap L_b(\mathbb R)$ such that for all $p \in [a,b]$ we have $g(p) = \|f\|_p$?
If we replace $f \in L_a(\mathbb R) \cap L_b(\mathbb R)$ with $f \in L_a([0,1]) \cap L_b([0,1])$, then the function $p \mapsto \|f\|_p$ is nondecreasing — we could similarly ask if every nondecreasing function is attained this way.
Similarly, if we $f \in L_a(\mathbb R) \cap L_b(\mathbb R)$ with $f \in L_a(\mathbb Z) \cap L_b(\mathbb Z)$, then we could ask whether every nonincreasing function of the form $p \mapsto \|f\|_p$.

If I remember correctly, there's some convexity condition on $g$ that you can get if $g : p \mapsto \lVert f \rVert_p$, though I don't remember the details: maybe that $g(1/p)$ or $\log g(1/p)$ is convex on $[1/b, 1/a]$ or something like that.

See chapter on $L^{p}$ spaces in Rudin's RCA. $p \mapsto \ln \int |f|^{p}$ is convex.

@geetha290krm Thanks! This is Exercise III.4. The result holds for any measure space apparently…
